# Excel VBA: Loop through cells and copy values to another workbook

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I already spent hours on this problem, but I didn't succeed in finding a working solution.

Here is my **problem description**:

I want to loop through a certain range of cells in one workbook and copy values to another workbook. Depending on the current column in the first workbook, I copy the values into a different sheet in the second workbook.
When I execute my code, I always get the `runtime error 439: object does not support this method or property`.

My **code** looks more or less like this:

```
Sub trial()

Dim Group As Range
Dim Mat As Range
Dim CurCell_1 As Range
Dim CurCell_2 As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set CurCell_1 = Range("B3") 'starting point in wb 1

For Each Group in Workbooks("My_WB_1").Worksheets("My_Sheet").Range("B4:P4")
    Set CurCell_2 = Range("B4") 'starting point in wb 2
    For Each Mat in Workbooks("My_WB_1").Worksheets("My_Sheet").Range("A5:A29")
        Set CurCell_1 = Cells(Mat.Row, Group.Column) 'Set current cell in the loop
        If Not IsEmpty(CurCell_1)
            Workbooks("My_WB_2").Worksheets(CStr(Group.Value)).CurCell_2.Value = Workbooks("My_WB_1").Worksheets("My_Sheet").CurCell_1.Value 'Here it break with runtime error '438 object does not support this method or property
            CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1,0) 'Move one cell down
        End If
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I've done extensive research and I know how to copy values from one workbook to another if you're using explicit names for your objects (sheets & ranges), but I don't know why it does not work like I implemented it using variables.
I also searched on stackoverlow and -obviously- Google, but I didn't find a similar problem which would answer my question.

So my **question** is:
Could you tell me where the error in my code is or if there is another easier way to accomplish the same using a different way?

This is my first question here, so I hope everything is fine with the format of my code, the question asked and the information provided. Otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**5 Things...**

**1)** You don't need this line

`Set CurCell_1 = Range("B3") 'starting point in wb 1`

This line is pointless as you are setting it inside the loop

**2)** You are setting this in a loop every time

`Set CurCell_2 = Range("B4")`

Why would you be doing that? It will simply overwrite the values every time. Also which sheet is this range in??? (See Point 5)

**3)**`CurCell_2` is a Range and as JohnB pointed it out, it is not a method.

Change

`Workbooks("My_WB_2").Worksheets(CStr(Group.Value)).CurCell_2.Value = Workbooks("My_WB_1").Worksheets("My_Sheet").CurCell_1.Value`

to

`CurCell_2.Value = CurCell_1.Value`

**4)** You cannot assign range by just setting an "=" sign

`CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1,0)`

Change it to

`Set CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1,0)`

**5)** Always specify full declarations when working with two or more objects so that there is less confusion. Your code can also be written as

```
Option Explicit

Sub trial()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Group As Range, Mat As Range
    Dim CurCell_1 As Range, CurCell_2 As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("My_WB_1")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("My_WB_2")
    
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("My_Sheet")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Sheet2") '<~~ Change as required

    For Each Group In ws1.Range("B4:P4")
        '~~> Why this?
        Set CurCell_2 = ws2.Range("B4")
        For Each Mat In ws1.Range("A5:A29")
            Set CurCell_1 = ws1.Cells(Mat.Row, Group.Column)
            If Not IsEmpty(CurCell_1) Then
                CurCell_2.Value = CurCell_1.Value
                Set CurCell_2 = CurCell_2.Offset(1)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me a lot! I changed my code according to your suggestions and it run immediately as it should!  
Concering your point **2)**: Actually you're right, the sheet is missing. If I understood you right, then a Range refers to a specific cell, a sheet and a workbook, not only a cell. But since I move this range using *Offset* in every inner loop, I have to reset it in the outer loop.

Comment: `If I understood you right, then a Range refers to a specific cell, a sheet and a workbook, not only a cell.` No :) A `Range` represents a cell, a row, a column, or a selection of cells that contains one or more contiguous blocks of cells IN a Sheet.

Answer (score 2):

```
Workbooks("My_WB_2").Worksheets(CStr(Group.Value)).CurCell_2.Value
```

This will not work, since CurCell_2 is not a method of Worksheet, but a variable. Replace by

```
Workbooks("My_WB_2").Worksheets(CStr(Group.Value)).Range("B4").Value
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Sounds very logical to me.  
So now I clearly understand why the error message occurs.
  
But how would you write the code if the range at the end is not always Range("B4"), but rather a changing range defined by the variable CurCell_2?

Comment: CurCell_2.Value = ... ? Or something like ...Range (aVariableContainingAStringDefiningTheRange).Value = ...